# htaccess: How to redirect to non-www domain in subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects to the non-www version of a domain, but if I'm in a subfolder like `https://www.example.com/test/` nothing happens. How can my code affect subfolders too?

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPS_HOST` does not exist, [read the Apache HTTPD documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

> The following variables provide the values of the named HTTP request
>   headers.
>
> #### Name
>
> - HTTP_ACCEPT
> - HTTP_COOKIE
> - HTTP_FORWARDED
> - HTTP_HOST
> - HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION
> - HTTP_REFERER
> - HTTP_USER_AGENT

Given that `HTTPS_HOST` doesn't exist when `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` is matched you're rewrite wasn't working at all.

You should use in both cases `HTTP_HOST`, and given that your rewrites are identical for both HTTP and HTTPS why don't simply have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In case the suggested solution does not work I suggest to [enable rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging):

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

*Pay attention to not deploy such logging in production because it affects server performances*.

Comment: Why? But this doesn't answer my question regarding the subfolder issue.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Still it doesn't work with subfolders.

Comment: This is far strange, maybe you're behind a proxy or a load balancer.

Comment: I've updated again my answer, adding an `X-Forwarded-Proto` check if you're behind a load balancer or a proxy.

Comment: Hmm, no I'm not behind a proxy or a load balancer and I get redirected to my domain root without the subfolder. I can only make this work when "hardcoding" my url to `RewriteRule` like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/test [R=301,L]`.

Comment: Try to enable rewrite log [`LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)

Comment: I was thinking that your rewrites are identical for http and https, why don't remove the https check and use only one. I've updated my answer accordingly to this suggestion.